# Staging website redirects to live, can't find the cause

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins, staging

A bit of a headache for me. We have a staging website set up on a subdomain. But for some reason, two things are not going quite right.

1. There seems to be a relationship between plug-ins. If I deactivate a plug-in on staging, live also goes inactive. Is this because a copy of the other plug-in is from live?
2. For some reason it keeps redirecting from staging to live. In the header of the redirect, I see that it is initiated by WordPress, indicating that is a plug-in causing it. However, I cannot in any way find which plug-in is causing it. Is there an easy way to find out the specific plug-in causing it?

I am not allowed to post the website here as far as I know, to avoid "advertising," but I can provide the URLs if desired.

Comment: Did you change all internal links in the database when changing to liver server? It sounds as if the links are still pointing to your staging environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this inside your wp-config.php to the dev site,
After that use plugins
WP Migrate Lite to replace all urls from db (in this plugin there is a function to find and replace,use it  for search through db and replace all url's left befind of live site from DB.

define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );